# Draw NSBitmapImageRep in NSImageView

Tags: cocoa, xcode, image

How can I draw a NSBitmapImageRep in a NSImageView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[bitmapRep CGImage] size:NSMakeSize(width,height)];
```

Then:

```
[imageView setImage:image];
```

Another possibility is by turning it into a TIFF ( - (NSData *)TIFFRepresentation ) and using that to create the NSImage object, but that could create quite some overhead.

Also keep in mind that the method of NSBitmapImageRep - (CGImageRef)CGImage is 10.5 or higher.

**Edit:**

For a cleaner solution look at @Ken's answer.

Comment: That technically works, but is roundabout.  An NSImage is a container for NSImageReps.  So if you have a rep, just put it in an image.  Dropping to CG is a little random.

Comment: @Ken haven't tried this, its what I could find in the NSBitmapImageRep class reference :P

Answer (score 13):

```
NSImage *im = [[[NSImage alloc] init] autorelease];
[im addRepresentation:bitmapRep];
[imageView setImage:im];
```